# How to retrieve data from database based on selected value in combo box?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Im new to c# here. I have a comboBox codes that enable user to choose month and dates. When user click cmdSend button, the program will retrieve the month & date form comboBox and call dbConnect.Select class function to do the select mysql statement.

```
private void cmdSend_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string>[] list;
        list = dbConnect.Select(month_list.Text, year_list.Text);

        printer_info.Rows.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < list[0].Count; i++)
        {
            int number = printer_info.Rows.Add();
            printer_info.Rows[number].Cells[0].Value = list[0][i];
            printer_info.Rows[number].Cells[1].Value = list[1][i];
            printer_info.Rows[number].Cells[2].Value = list[2][i];
            printer_info.Rows[number].Cells[3].Value = list[3][i];
        }
    }
```

the retrieve database class:

```
public List<string>[] Select(string month,string year)
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM page_counter where month ='" + month + "' AND year ='" + year + "' ;";

        //Create a list to store the result
        List<string>[] list = new List<string>[4];
        list[0] = new List<string>();
        list[1] = new List<string>();
        list[2] = new List<string>();
        list[3] = new List<string>();

        //Open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //Create Command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            //Create a data reader and Execute the command
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //Read the data and store them in the list
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                list[0].Add(dataReader["id"].ToString() + "");
                list[1].Add(dataReader["month"].ToString() + "");
                list[2].Add(dataReader["year"].ToString() + "");
                list[3].Add(dataReader["page_count"].ToString() + "");
            }

            //close Data Reader
            dataReader.Close();

            //close Connection
            this.CloseConnection();

            //return list to be displayed
            return list;
        }
        else
        {
            return list;
        }
    }
```

However this code does not work, can someone advise me please?

EDITED:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM page_counter where month = @month  AND year = @year;";
//Open connection
if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
{
//Create Command
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month",month);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year",year );

//Create a data reader and Execute the command
    MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

//Read the data and store them in the list
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        list[0].Add(dataReader["id"].ToString() + "");
        list[1].Add(dataReader["month"].ToString() + "");
        list[2].Add(dataReader["year"].ToString() + "");
        list[3].Add(dataReader["page_count"].ToString() + "");
    }  

    //close Data Reader
    dataReader.Close();
```

I have edited the code as suggested,However I have an error on the AddWithValue, it say : does not contain a definition for AddWithValue and no extension method AddWithValue, I have added the Data.MySqlClient reference but still remain the same. Please advise.

Comment: is it asp.net or winform??

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri It is winform c#.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1 :** You need to use `SelectedItem` property of the combobox to get the selected item from it.

**Solution 1:**

Replace This:

```
list = dbConnect.Select(month_list.Text, year_list.Text);
```

With This:

```
list = dbConnect.Select(month_list.SelectedItem.ToString(),        
                         year_list.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

**Problem 2:**

i beilve that your `Month` and `Year` columns in your `Database` are `INT` columns.if they are `INT` columns you dont need to enclose the `month` and `year` parameter values within single quotes.

**Solution 2:**

Try This:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM page_counter where month =  
                   " + month + " AND year =" + year + " ;";
```

**Suggestion :** Your query is open to sql injection attacks i'd suggest to use Parameterised queries to avoid them.

Try This with Parameterised queries:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM page_counter where month = @month  AND year = @year;";
//Open connection
if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
{
  //Create Command
  MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month",month);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year",year );

       //Remaining same

        //Create a data reader and Execute the command
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //Read the data and store them in the list
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            list[0].Add(dataReader["id"].ToString() + "");
            list[1].Add(dataReader["month"].ToString() + "");
            list[2].Add(dataReader["year"].ToString() + "");
            list[3].Add(dataReader["page_count"].ToString() + "");
        }

        //close Data Reader
        dataReader.Close();
```

Comment: Why I have an error on AddWithValue? and should I remain the MysqlDataReader line?

Comment: @Ren; yes you have to keep the remaning same, check my edited answer.

Comment: How about the AddWithValue error?any idea why i receive the error?

Comment: @Ren: i don't have an idea about which error you are talking about.could you please edit your question with error?

Comment: It say'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddWithValue' and no extension method 'AddWithValue' accepting a first argument of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)